# Creating an ASP.net WebService that returns JSON instead of XML

Tags: android, asp.net, xml, json, web-services

Maybe the method is returning how it should, but I basically just made a test method that looks like this

```
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string TestJSON()
    {
        var location = new Location[2];
        location[0] = new Location();
        location[0].Latitute = "19";
        location[0].Longitude = "27";
        location[1] = new Location();
        location[1].Latitute = "-81.9";
        location[1].Longitude = "28";

        return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(location);
    }
```

When i hit this from my android application I get an exception like this

```
Value <?xml of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

I thought this method would return just straight JSON, but this is what the web service method returns

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">[{"Latitute":"19","Longitude":"27"},{"Latitute":"-81.9","Longitude":"28"}]</string>
```

Is it suppose to be like this? Is there a way to remove the XML stuff that is outside the JSON?  I'm not sure what I have to do in my webservice to make it return the correct format of data

Code Using on Android to Call the Webservice

```
   public String readWebService(String method)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://myserver.com/WebService.asmx/" + method);


    Log.d(main.class.toString(), "Created HttpGet Request object");

    try
    {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
        Log.d(main.class.toString(), "Created HTTPResponse object");
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        Log.d(main.class.toString(), "Got Status Line");
        int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode == 200) {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream content = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(line);
            }

            return builder.toString();
        } else {
            Log.e(main.class.toString(), "Failed to contact Web Service: Status Code: " + statusCode);
        }
    }
    catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        Log.e(main.class.toString(), "ClientProtocolException hit");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(main.class.toString(), "IOException hit");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(main.class.toString(), "General Exception hit");
    }

    return "WebService call failed";    
}
```

then I would call that method somewhere in the code like

```
try {
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(readWebService("TestJSON"));
    Log.i(main.class.toString(), "Number of entries " + jsonArray.length());
        ....
}
...
```

Comment: How are you calling this from android? Are you specifying any contentype in that request?

Comment: I wasn't but I just tried adding httpGet.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");  when I add this the webservice returns a 500 server error status code.  I'll update my question to include the android code I'm using to call the web service method

Comment: Looks like someone else was having a similar problem that I missed during my extensive research (5 min googling) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058454/asp-net-webservice-is-wrapping-my-json-reponse-with-xml-tags?rq=1 ...apparently it works if I use a POST instead of a get with the content type set to application/json

Answer (score 2):

try this code.it will help you.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/45275/Create-a-JSON-WebService-in-ASP-NET-2-0-with-a-jQu