# Using ASP.Net session in Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, session

I have to process an operation in Javascript using data stored in session (`System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Filtre"]`)

Is it even possible to catch and do operation in Javascript using the asp.net session ?

I already tried some sample like this one without success :

```
var f = '<%=Session["Filtre"]%>';
```

In the case where this is impossible (for security issues I guess), is it possible to call a aspx.cs function in javascript who will perform the operation ?

Have a good day.

Comment: Why don't you store your information during Page_Load into a variable, and then access this variable in your page?

Comment: Because my project use iframe, and my component .ascx isn't reload at every page ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot mix client side javascript and server side code (such as sessions). The processes do *not* run at the same time.

Your code

```
var f = '<%=Session["Filtre"]%>';
```

could work, BUT:

- First the server needs to execute the `<%  %>` block to generate a string, which is placed in some text
- That text is sent to the browser, possibly as part of a page
- Only in the browser it is interpreted and executed as javascript

There is no **easy** way for the browser to execute random server side code. 
**Complicated** ways use AJAX calls to call specifically designed methods on the server (instead of arbitrary code).

Answer (score 0):

using `<scriptmanager>` you can do

Please go through the below article

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/525364/AJAX-for-Beginners-Part-3-Calling-Server-Side-Meth

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your JavaScript can call a C# method if you annotate the method with `WebMethod`. This makes the method callable from remote Web clients (i.e. it becomes a 'page method'). [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.webmethodattribute(v=vs.110).aspx).

You would need the [EnableSession](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.webmethodattribute.enablesession(v=vs.110).aspx) property set to true in order to use the Session. Example:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession=true)]
public static int Example() {
...
```

Then call the page method from JavaScript, probably [using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19243303/397817).

```
   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "MyPage.aspx/Example",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: "{ }",
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert(langError + " " + textStatus); },
        success: function (msg) {
            alert(msg.d);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I'm not sure if the EnableSession attribute is actually needed for page methods (vs web methods) and don't currently have access to my development environment, but you can try it.