# string being appened to json output

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to use json.net to produce a web service but I am a bit perplexed as to why  < string >  is showing in the dummy data

```
[WebMethod]
public string getCustomerInfo(string IVACode)
{
  var customerData = _dal.apertureAppstblCustomers.Where(a => a.IVACode == IVACode).ToList();

 var jsonstring = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customerData);
        return jsonstring;
}
```

ie its starting like `<string>` and ending `</string>` how do i get it to display CustomerInformationinstead of string is it good practise to be naming the nodes?.

> [{"id":"7aee450a-a9a7-4f19-83d3-467a3b8a39c0","IVACode":"IVA002","FirstName":"Peter","LastName":"Carson","AddressLine1":"Waters Edge Belfast","AddressLine2":null,"Town":"Belfast","County":"Down","PostCode":"BT99YXX","Telephone":null,"EmailAddress":"email","isActive":true,"authUserName":null,"authCreatedDate":null,"personalProgressValue":null,"contributionsToDate":null,"totalContributions":null,"totalArrears":50000.00,"totalPaid":null,"isDeleted":false,"deviceId":null,"deviceOs":null}]

Comment: If I understand it correctly when a webclient calls getCustomerInfo they get the content wrapped in `<string></string>` element? What is the base class of your webservice? If you inspect jsonstring with the debugger before it is returned, does it contain that `<string></string>` wrapper already? How do you test your method?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET WebService is Wrapping my JSON response with XML tags](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2058454/10263)

Comment: It is not a duplicate as I am using the json.net libary not the .net core funcitonallity

Answer (score 0):

You will need to convert the serialized string back to your object and then consume it to show the relevant information.

Example below.

JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonstring)

Comment: I understand that what i am asking is why is string produced on the selizaration of the object not how to deserlize the object  why would i deslizare after just serailizing it

Comment: Do you really understand the question before posting an answer?

Comment: @david, that comment was for the owner of the answer and not you.

Comment: @Rahul, the response that he posted didn't exactly make that very clear.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't get that in the serialized string but you can replace those tokens using `Replace()` string function like

```
jsonstring = jsonstring.Replace("<string>","").Replace("</string>","");
```

Comment: What is proper approach here Rahul should I have a starting tag or just simply return the data.

Comment: @david, as mentioned in answer you can repalce those tokens and then return the string.