# Ajax query to my webservices is returning xml in my json

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

I am having this exact problem as raised in this question

[ASP.NET JSON web service always return the JSON response wrapped in XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121559/asp-net-json-web-service-always-return-the-json-response-wrapped-in-xml)

It's late and I have been sitting in this chair for 10 hours now trying to get ajax and json to work and all I got was deeply frustrated.

So does anyone know how to make my webservice not return my json object wrapped in xml?  If I just do a straight dataType: "json" then I get nothing. I have to do dataType: "jsonp" to get anything back from the server at all.  But once I do jsonp I get my json wrapped in xml.

Please help
Thanks
Cheryl

Comment: Can you post your service code and how you're calling it with jQuery?

Comment: I would like to see the code where you call the ajax and the web service code, including any decorations you have on the method.

Answer (score 3):

If you set the response type to `json` [jQuery is then checking the response to see if it's valid JSON](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L493) (and since it's XML, that's not the case)...when it's not valid, it silently fails since **jQuery 1.4+**.

There are 3 important bits when making your request, [by default it needs to be a `POST`](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/04/04/json-hijacking-and-how-asp-net-ajax-1-0-mitigates-these-attacks.aspx) and you need to set the `contentType` to `"application/json; charset=utf-8"` like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'MyService.asmx/Method',
  type: 'POST',
  data: myData,
  dataType: 'json',
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  success: function(data) {
    //do something with data
  }
});
```

Then on the server-side make sure you have the [`ScriptService` attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.services.scriptserviceattribute.aspx) set, here's an example *very* minimal layout:

```
[WebService] //here by default when you create the service
[ScriptService]
public class MyService : System.Web.Services.WebService 
{
  [WebMethod]
  public MyObject MyMethod(int id) 
  {
    return new MyObject();
  }
}
```

Comment: If I do a Post I get 403 Forbidden error.  If I do a json and get I get a 500 Internal Server Error.  But if I do a jsonp and get I get the results but it's wrapped in xml rather than just straight json.  

I am going to try to do a $.getJSON() to see if that helps.

Comment: @Cheryl - What internal server error are you getting? Your event log should say, or attach a debugger.