# Ajax query to my webservices is returning xml in my json - Part 2

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, jsonp

It's me again ([previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357932/ajax-query-to-my-webservices-is-returning-xml-in-my-json)) I am still having problems with json and xml being returned from an ajax call.

I have written a webservice in MonoDevelop version 2.2 to return my json.

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string  getLocationJ(){}
```

Which returns:-

```
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string json = js.Serialize(bigPM);
return json;
```

If I test my webservice I get:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">[{"placeName":"XXXX","address":"Some    Address","lat":12121,"lng":12121}]</string>
```

Which is exactly what I am pulling in when I make my ajax calls.  My json is still wrapped in XML and therefore cannot be read.

This is my ajax call:-

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: theURL,
  async: true,
  data: {minLong:minLon, maxLong:maxLon, minLat:minLat, maxLat:maxLat},
  cache: false,
  dataType: "jsonp",
  contentType: "application/xml; charset=utf-8",
  success: function (data) {
    alert('in here');



  },
  error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                alert(xhr.status);
                alert(thrownError);
                alert(xhr.statusText);
            }  
  });
```

If I do just json I get 500 Internal server error, if I do a POST I get 403 forbidden error.

This morning I tried doing:-

```
$.getJSON(theURL, {minLong:minLon, maxLong:maxLon, minLat:minLat, maxLat:maxLat}, function(data) {
 );
});
```

Only I get the exact same problems.

If I could just remove the xml from my json then I could move forward but right now I am dead in the water and I think I am drowning in ajax!

Please help
Cheryl

Comment: This is not a Javascript problem. Your server is what's putting the XML wrapper around the string, so it's some sort of configuration problem there.

Comment: What I find interesting is that I was following this example 

http://williamsportwebdeveloper.com/cgi/wp/?p=494

And if you test his webservices they both return the json wrapped in XML. But he is also doing a 'POST' in his ajax calls.  Perhaps I should also be doing a POST.  But with a POST I get 403 forbidden.  Do you think this is due to the fact that I am calling HTTPS?  How can I get around the 403 error?  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of returning a string in your WebMethod, return void and use:

```
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
Context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(YOUR_STRING_TO_OUTPUT));
```

Comment: Please dont' copy and paste your answers to multiple questions. If the questions are different, please make your answers unique to the question asked. If the questions are the same, they should be flagged or closed (which you don't have the reputation to do as of yet).

Answer (score 0):

change

```
contentType: "application/xml; charset=utf-8",
```

to

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

Complete example:

```
/* in this case I am using */
       <script src="Js/json2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  // available at: http://www.json.org/js.html

function jsonObject()
{
};
var phoneListObject = new jsonObject();

function SaveJsonObject()
{
    phoneListObject.Control = new jsonObject();
    phoneListObject.Control.CustomerId = $("#CustomerId").val();
    phoneListObject.Control.CustomerName = $("#CustomerName").val();
    phoneListObject.ListBody.PhonesBlock = new jsonObject();
    phoneListObject.ListBody.PhonesBlock.Phone = new Array();
    $('#PhonesBlock .Phone').each(function(myindex)
    {
        phoneListObject.ListBody.PhonesBlock.Phone[myindex].PhoneNumber = $(".PhoneNumber input", this).val();
        phoneListObject.ListBody.PhonesBlock.Phone[myindex].PhoneName = $(".PhoneName input", this).val();
     });
 };

 $(function()
{
    function SaveCurrentList()
    {
        SaveJsonObject();
        var currentSet = phoneListObject;
        var formData = { FormData: currentSet };
        phoneListJSON = JSON.stringify(formData);
        var FormData = "{ FormData:" + JSON.stringify(phoneListJSON) + "}";
        SavePhoneListData(FormData);
    };
    function SavePhoneListData(phonesData)
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: phonesData,
            dataFilter: function(data)
            {
                var msg;
                if ((typeof (JSON) !== 'undefined') &&
        (typeof (JSON.parse) === 'function'))
                    msg = JSON.parse(data);
                else
                    msg = eval('(' + data + ')');
                if (msg.hasOwnProperty('d'))
                    return msg.d;
                else
                    return msg;
            },
            url: "../../WebServices/ManagePhones.asmx/SaveJson",
            success: function(msg)
            {
                SaveSuccess(msg);/* the JSON is in the msg, create this function to do what you want with it. */
            },
            complete: function(xhr, textresponse)
            {
                var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
            },
            error: function(msg)
            {
            },
            failure: function(msg)
            {
            }
        });
    };
    $('#btnSave').click(function()
    {
        SaveCurrentList();
    });
});

/* json data snip */
{"FormData":{"Control":{"CustomerId":"12345y6","CustomerName":"Joe Customer"},"PhonesBlock":{"Phone":[{"PhoneNumber":"234-233-2322","PhoneName":"son harry"},{"PhoneNumber":"234-233-2323","PhoneName":"son frank"},{"PhoneNumber":"234-233-2320","PhoneName":"momk"}]}}}

/*XML of the form data:*/
<FormData>
    <Control>
        <CustomerId>12345y6</CustomerId>
        <CustomerName>Joe Customer</CustomerName>
    </Control>
    <PhonesBlock>
        <Phone>
            <PhoneNumber>234-233-2322</PhoneNumber>
            <PhoneName>son harry</PhoneName>
        </Phone>
        <Phone>
            <PhoneNumber>234-233-2323</PhoneNumber>
            <PhoneName>son frank</PhoneName>
        </Phone>
        <Phone>
            <PhoneNumber>234-233-2321</PhoneNumber>
            <PhoneName>momk</PhoneName>
        </Phone>
    </PhonesBlock>
</FormData>

/* form layout snip */

<div class="control">
    <div class="customer">
        <input typeof="text" id="CutomerId" />
        <input typeof="text" id="CutomerName" />
    </div>
    <div class="phoneslist" id="PhonesBlock">
        <div class="Phone">
            <input typeof="text" class="PhoneNumber" />
            <input typeof="text" class="PhoneName" />
        </div>
        <div class="Phone">
            <input typeof="text" class="PhoneNumber" />
            <input typeof="text" class="PhoneName" />
        </div>
        <div class="Phone">
            <input typeof="text" class="PhoneNumber" />
            <input typeof="text" class="PhoneName" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<input id="buttonSave" class="myButton" type="button" value="Save" />
```

signature of the web service method:

```
   [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public string SaveJson(string FormData)
    {
    }
```

Comment: ooops too bad I left that in by mistake - I have done that and it makes no difference I still have my json wrapped in xml.

Comment: You could try using the serializer class from: http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx

Comment: whether I do json or xml I keep getting this response in firebug:-

missing ; before statement

<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">[{...nue","lat":-79.45,"lng":43.6801},{"pla

Comment: Yes, that would be due to the XML markup around your JSON text. You need to fix your server. This is not a problem with your jQuery code.

Comment: yes I agree the problem definitely lies on the server - but any suggestions as to how to fix it?

Comment: I'd help if I could but I know nothing about "MonoDevelop".

Comment: I have seen other asp.net servers also returning json wrapped in xml so I don't beleive my problem lies with the server.  I think I should be doing a Post not a Get. But with a Post I get 403 Forbidden.  Does anyone know how to get around that problem?

Comment: I agree it should be Post not Get and as such it should be json not jsonp for the dataType.  The 403 error indicates (to me at least) that you might have a cross domain issue in play in the url.  Is that from the same site (Domain)?

Comment: Also, your `data:` appears to be incorrect and should be serialized.  I use the one from http://www.json.org/ (json2.js) to serialize my client side stuff for this.  I will add and example of that above.

Comment: One other note, not being familiar with MonoDevelop config, I can only toss out a link http://vampirebasic.blogspot.com/2009/04/aspnet-ajax-in-mono.html but I have no first hand experience with that.

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty fix is to extract your json from the xml in the success function.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: theURL,
  async: true,
  data: {minLong:minLon, maxLong:maxLon, minLat:minLat, maxLat:maxLat},
  cache: false,
  dataType: "jsonp",
  contentType: "application/xml; charset=utf-8",
  success: function (data) {

data = extractJsonFromXml(data); 
  //you have to write extractJsonFromXml function in js, you could use substring, or a regex replace. 

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your service class has [ScriptService] attribute. This attribute is not added by default.